# Meaning clarification about「扱う」and 「禁じ手」 in this sentence

Tags: translation, meaning

The parts marked in bold are what I am unsure about in this sentence...

「すでに敵対組織はかなり掃討されたのに、麻薬の流通量がちっとも減らないのは、謎のボスが**禁じ手**のはずだった麻薬を**扱いだしている**からなんじゃないのか、と思うんだが...」

The dictionary entries of 「**禁じ手**」usually are limited to 'unallowed moves' or fouls in sports; however judging from this sentence I believe it can mean something like 'taboo' as well. Furthermore I was struggling with understanding 「**扱いだして**」but I think it means something  like 'starting to sell/handle/etc.' here.

In short my questions are whether my understanding of above-mentioned is correct or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have basically answered your own questions, so I will be brief.

"Taboo" is an excellent translation for 「禁{きん}じ手{て}」.

The 「手」 in this word originally means "a move or technique" used in sumo, shogi, go, etc. 「禁じ手」, therefore, originally refers to a prohibited technique or move in those sports and games.

The 「だす」 in 「扱{あつか}いだす」 is 「出す」.  When 「出す」 is used as a subsidiary verb, it is often written in kana and it means "to start ~~ing".

Answer (score 4):

You are absolutely right.

「禁じ手」usually means 'foul play' in sports.
But in this sentence, it is used as a metaphorical expression.
「扱う」has the closest meaning to "handle" in this sentence.